# Unable to fill Dropdown list

Tags: angularjs

I am filling **3 Dropdown lists**  using **Angular js** 
 
Based on first dropdown selection , second dropdown will fill, and based on second dropdown third dropdown will fill.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="option1" ng-options="option for option in options1" ng-change="getOptions2()">
    </select>
    <select ng-model="option2" ng-options="option for option in options2" ng-change="getOptions3()">
    </select>
    <select ng-model="option3" ng-options="option for option in options3">
    </select>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
var option1Options = ["Men", "Women", "Kids"];
var option2Options = [["Top wear","Bottom wear","Blazers"],
               ["W-Top Wear","W-Bottom Wear","W-Blazers"],
               ["K-Top wear","K-Bottom wear","K-others"]];
var option3Options = [["M-Tshirts","M-Casula Shirts","option2 - 3-3"],
               ["M-Jeans","option2 - 3-2","option2 - 3-3"],
               ["M-Blazers","option2 - 3-2","option2 - 3-3"],
               ["w-Tshirts","w-Casula Shirts","w-option2 - 3-3"]];

function myCtrl($scope){
    $scope.options1 = option1Options;
    $scope.options2 = []; 
    $scope.options3 = [];

    $scope.getOptions2 = function(){
        var key = $scope.options1.indexOf($scope.option1);
        var myNewOptions = option2Options[key];

        $scope.options2 = myNewOptions;
    };

    $scope.getOptions3 = function(){

        var key = $scope.options2.indexOf($scope.option2);
        var myNewOptions = option3Options[key];

        $scope.options3 = myNewOptions;
    };
}
```

**Fiddle Link** : http://jsfiddle.net/mayankBisht/Xku9z/513/

**Problem**

- When I am trying to fill third dropdown with womens options, it's still showing Mens options. 
  Please help.

Comment: The options you select for the third drop-down do not depend at all on what you selected in the first. You're just using the index of the selected option of the second dropdown to choose what to display in the third. You need to take into accound what was selected in the first, too.

Comment: Could you change the data structure of the options? You should have one array of object for each options array whit a type property to filter based on selected option of the previous select.

Comment: @The.Bear  please provide an example .